# Cannot get alpha to work with ggplot2::geom_sf on sf linestring object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

This requires the libraries sf and ggplot2 in R. I have a sf object with 4 linestrings. 3 of these are identical and one is extended:

```
a <- st_linestring(rbind(c(2,2), c(3,3), c(3,2)))
b <- st_linestring(rbind(c(2,2), c(3,3)))
c <- st_linestring(rbind(c(2,2), c(3,3)))
d <- st_linestring(rbind(c(2,2), c(3,3)))

testsf <- st_sf(object = c(1, 2, 3, 4), geometry = st_sfc(a, b, c, d), crs = 4326)`
```

If I plot this in ggplot2 with alpha = 0.1, I would expect that the diagonal line is darker than the vertical line as it occurs more often. This is normal (non-sf) behaviour in ggplot2.

```
 ggplot(data = testsf) + geom_sf(data = testsf, alpha = 0.1, lwd = 2, color = "black")
```

However, all lines appear to be equal alpha. Why is this occurring?

**Update**: If i try

```
testsf %<>% dplyr::mutate(geochar = as.character(geometry)) %>% dplyr::group_by(geochar) %>% dplyr::tally() %>% sf::st_cast()

ggplot(data = testsf) + geom_sf(data = testsf, aes(alpha = n),  lwd = 2, color = "black")
```

the legend shows alpha changing as if it is a polygon...perhaps geom_sf is not properly handling alpha for lines (note, above code requires dplyr and magrittr packages)

Comment: Have you tried putting `alpha=0.1` inside `aes()`?

Comment: Is `geom_sf` actually part of the `sf` package? When I installed and loaded `sf` I still got the following error `could not find function "geom_sf"`.

Comment: geom_sf is part of the ggplot2 package. You may need to install the dev version: `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`

Comment: J. Con: `aes(alpha = 0.1)` does not work

Answer (score 2):

I filed an issue at github.com/edzer/sf.

https://github.com/edzer/sfr/issues/311#issuecomment-296752334

This is not yet supported in geom_sf. Hopefully in the near future...